Device hangs after ESP32 Guru Meditation Error
Getting a Guru Meditation Error on ESP32. The device hangs and need a manual reset. I do have a watchdog set up, and was hoping that when ESP32 is hanging, watchdog would reset it, which is not happening.
Below code shows how the watchdog is used in my code.
In the init function
  esp_task_wdt_init(360, true); 
  esp_task_wdt_add(NULL);  

In the loop
  esp_task_wdt_reset(); 

Additional detail that might helpful. The Guru Meditation Error happens in task function. void LoopMqttConnControlTask(void * pvParameters) which is started via below
void StartMqttConnControlTask() {
    
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
      LoopMqttConnControlTask, 
      "StartMqttConnControlTask", 
      10000, 
      NULL,      
      5,         
      &mqttConnControlTask, 
      1
    );        
}

